# Best Magento Version for Starters

Tags: magento

This is my first time using Magento and was currently using Magento 2.4.5 but I already got into issues such as product images not showing also already tried to applied every solutions I found in the internet There's also where the minicart is not updating even though I already add to cart a product. So I'm just assuming it might be because of version. So which version of Magento could you recommend especially for starters?

I also tried Magento 2.4.6 but still got the same issue.

Comment: I think you setup the wrong version php for magento version 2.4.5 and version 2.4.6 so you get these issue. It should be php version 8.1 for both magento version.